# How to use two different Python Versions in the same File or Project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, cntk

I have written some code in cntk, which needs Python Version 3.6 or older. The problem is that I want to use this code in a Project, which only allows Python 3.8 or newer. What's the best solution to combine these two programms?

EDIT:
The 3.6 code does some deep learning predictions, which should be called from the 3.8 project to use them for other computations.

Comment: Depends on what both codes do. Please provide more detail. [Ask]

Comment: The 3.6 code does some deep learning predictions, which should be called from the 3.8 project to use them for other computations.

Comment: If you're fine with writing out the results of one code to a file and reading that file in the other code then sure. Remember that _you_ pick which python interpreter to use when you enter the command in the terminal. If you can't go through a file, then what you want is probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows they get installed to separate folders, "C:\python26" and "C:\python31", but the executables have the same "python.exe" name.

I created another "C:\python" folder that contains "python.bat" and "python3.bat" that serve as wrappers to "python26" and "python31" respectively, and added "C:\python" to the PATH environment variable.

This allows me to type python or python3 in my .bat Python wrappers to start the one I desire.

On Linux, you can use the #! trick to specify which version you want a script to use.